# U-boot: SPL - undefined reference 'file_fat_write'

Tags: u-boot, fat

I am trying to write a file to SD card in spl_mmc.c. During compilation
gcc moans: undefined reference 'file_fat_write'. I don't understand why.
Directly after the (original) code in mmc_load_image_fat():

err = file_fat_read(payloadname,
                (u8 *)spl_image.load_addr, 0);

I insert the following code:

file_fat_write("foo", "foo", 3);

Why doesn't gcc know this function as it is also declared in
include/fat.h just as file_fat_read() is?

Did someone manage to write to fat out of the SPL?

Best,
André

Comment: What are the defines that you enable during SPL build? Did you enable FAT support for SPL build?

Comment: During my last tests I enabled CONFIG_FAT_WRITE. Now gcc does not complain anymore, however the SPL gets too large to fit into SRAM. Do you know how to enable it in u-boot instead of the SPL?

Comment: That is the problem of enabling FAT support in SPL. SPL is designed to be very small. FAT code is large. If you want to enable FAT support in the main u-boot just define the FAT outside the SPL context. Make sure your u-boot version supports FAT write! Older versions of u-boot do not support this feature.